# makefile: path given after -I but header file not found

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest

I am trying to use Google Test framework: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest .

I have 4 files:

factorial.cpp:

```
#include "factorial.h"

int factorial(int n) { [some code here] }
```

facotrial.h:

```
int factorial(int n);
```

test_factorial.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "factorial.h"

[some tests here]
```

gtest_main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n");
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Also I have a makefile which contains (among other things):

```
INCLUDES = -I/home/my_username/Documents/gtest/googletest/googletest/include
[...]
$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

After writing `make` in terminal I get:

```
test_factorial.cpp:1:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
makefile:27: recipe for target 'test_factorial.o' failed
```

What is the issue?

In the README file on googletest they say:

```
g++ -isystem ${GTEST_DIR}/include -pthread path/to/your_test.cc libgtest.a \
    -o your_test
```

So here it's `-isystem` instead of `-I` but I had problems with -isystem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added your includes to the *link* command, but not to the *compile* command.  This rule:

```
$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

tells how to *link* the main program from the object files.  This rule isn't used to compile the object files: assuming that your `[...]` doesn't elide a compile rule, you're using the built-in compiler rule which doesn't know anything about the `INCLUDES` variable.

If you would have shown us the compile command make printed when you got that error for `test_factorial.cpp` it would have been clear that the flag was missing.

If you don't make up your own variable to hold these flags and instead use the `CPPFLAGS` variable which is the standard variable for C preprocessor flags like `-I`, it will just work.

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/home/my_username/Documents/gtest/googletest/googletest/include
```

it may just work.